# Android AsyncTask Activity Crash RSS Reader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rss

I'm trying to build an RSS reader and put the rss feed fetch as ansyctask,
that returns a feed in list view, or returns a text view saying "no internet connection"
but the app still crashes, I don't know what's wrong, can you help please.

here is the code:

```
package rss;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.enporan.polytechoran.R;

public class RSSActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);


           rssfeedget alpha = new rssfeedget();
          alpha.execute();



    }

    private class rssfeedget extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FeedSource> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected FeedSource doInBackground(String... params) {
            FeedSource f = new HttpFeedSource();
            if(f!=null)
                return f;
            else {
               return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(FeedSource result){
            ListView rssItemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssListview);
            rssItemList.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            if(doInBackground()==null){
                TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                tv.setText("No internet Connection...");

            }
            else{

                RSSItemAdapter adapter = new RSSItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rssitem, doInBackground().getFeed());
                rssItemList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_news, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of Exception do you get? (my guess it is a networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: @coelho : Since the network code is executed in an AsyncTask, the NetworkOnMainThreadException shouldn't append. Larbi : could you add the stack trace in your post so we can help you?

Comment: @chteuchteu here is the error:

Comment: 12-29 20:08:33.902  22681-22681/com.enporan.polytechoran E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.enporan.polytechoran, PID: 22681
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at rss.NewsParser.parse(NewsParser.java:52)
            at rss.HttpFeedSource.getFeed(HttpFeedSource.java:17)

Comment: Told you. The problem is that you have to use network communication only in the doInBackground method and you are using it in the onPostExecute method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
private class rssfeedget extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RSSItem>> {
    private List<RSSItem> result;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected List<RSSItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
        FeedSource f = new HttpFeedSource();
        if(f.getFeed()==null)
            return null;
        else {
            this.result = f.getFeed(); // Execute getFeed in doInBackground
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RSSItem> result){


        if(doInBackground()==null){
            TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tv.setText("No internet Connection...");

        }
        else{
            ListView rssItemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssListview);
            rssItemList.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            RSSItemAdapter adapter = new RSSItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rssitem, this.result);
            rssItemList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @coelho pointed out, the `FeedSource.getFeed()` shouldn't be executed in the UI thread. You must now that the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods are executed inside the UI thread, while the `doInBackground` method isn't.

Here's what you can do: in your AsyncTask class, add a private member: `private List<RSSItem> result;` (replace RSSItem here by the type of the collection returned by getFeed).

Then, update `doInBackground`:

```
FeedSource f = new HttpFeedSource();
if (f != null)
    return f;
else {
    this.result = f.getFeed(); // Execute getFeed in doInBackground
    return null;
}
```

Then, in the `onPostExecute` method, you'll be able to use this private member as this:

```
RSSItemAdapter adapter = new RSSItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rssitem, this.result);
```

Comment: I applied that but it still crashes when no connection,,,
12-29 21:49:18.092  32101-32316/com.enporan.polytechoran E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.enporan.polytechoran, PID: 32101

Comment: Is it crashing when the phone doesn't have connection? Or is NetworkOnMainThreadException thrown?